# Problem training a TensorFlow model for captchas with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem with this TensorFlow model and I don't know what to do to make it accept the data correctly and start working.

This is a model intended to respond to captchas, but it is not working correctly. I think my method for collecting the data is correct, but I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to this.
Method for model:

```
mobilnet = hub.KerasLayer(self.url, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype="float32", name="img")
    self.model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            mobilnet,
            layers.Dropout(0.25),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.RepeatVector(10),
            layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True),
            layers.Dense(len(self.char_to_num.get_vocabulary()) + 1, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )
    self.model.summary()
    self.modelo.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

`

Method for collecting data.
`
def load_date2(self):

```
    image_names = os.listdir(self.datadir)
    labels = [name.split('.')[0] for name in image_names]
    # crea un dataframe con las rutas de archivo y las etiquetas
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'filename': image_names,
        'label': labels
    })
    
    # crea un generador de datos de imagen a partir del dataframe
    # datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)
    self.train_dataset = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        df,
        directory=self.datadir,
        x_col='filename',
        y_col='label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input',
        subset='training'
    )
    

    self.valid_dataset = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        df,
        directory=self.datadir,
        x_col='filename',
        y_col='label',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input',
        subset='validation'
    )`
```

Method for training
`

```
    log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    
    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=10, restore_best_weights=True),
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model_weights.h5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True),
       tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
    ]
    

    self.modelo.fit(
        self.train_dataset,
        validation_data=self.valid_dataset,
        epochs=self.epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        
    )
```

`
Error message:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 10, 21) are incompatible
```

If someone could help me with this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please rewrite your question and provide the error message you're getting.

Comment: Thank you very much already, I didn't realize that I had set up the question display incorrectly on the page